# JQuery event not fired when using "on"

Tags: jquery, events

I am creating a web app which using knockout to load page component html (and in turn the javascript of that part). I found a strange problem: when I use `$(selector).on('event', handler)`, then handler will never fired. But if I change it to `$(selector).live('event', handler)`, it will be good. I need to point out that when I call that event binding statement, the `$(selector).size() > 0`.

The same issue cause my `$(selector).validate({onfocusout: validator})` has no effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: BTW, I am using http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js

Comment: So you're loading the content dynamically?

Comment: Yes I do, I am loading the content dynamically by using knockoutjs's html binding

Comment: When jQuery compiles, it looks at the page as a whole and makes function/events available to the elements on the page. When you add content dynamically, you need to tell jQuery to check what is "live" on the page right now.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? live() was deprecated in 1.7 in favor for on(). Also 'event' should be replaced by actual event like 'click' but I realize it might be called 'event' for concise and readable purposes.

Comment: @limelights, see my comment above, the jquery version is 1.7.1. And 'event' in my statement is just a placeholder, it could be replaced with any real event

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, you are loading this content dynamically, which means you have to use a different syntax for your `on()` function.

```
$(document)
    .on("eventName", selector, handler(event){
        // handler
    });
```

This is a method that employs event bubbling. Instead of binding the event to existing elements, you are binding the event to the document and matching the element on which the event occurred to the selector and letting this event bubble up to the document level.

That being the case, it's better to use as close a parent as possible with this function instead of `document`. Keep in mind that this parent must exist on the page at load. The reason for this is to optimize performance and run smoother code.

If I understand the purpose of the second snippet, this should do the trick:

```
$(document)
    .on("blur", selector, function(){
        $(this).validate();
    });
```

We delegate the `blur` event to the elements matched by `selector` and validate them when the event occurs (`blur` occurs when focus on an element disappears).

Comment: This approach works! How to handle the `$(selector).validate({onfocusout: validator})` case then? My ugly workaround is put the validate statement into a setTimeout and give it 100 delay, I tried 1ms and 10ms delay and none of them works.

Comment: Try this: `$(document).on("blur", selector, function(){ $(this).validate(); });` (again, it's better not to use `document`).

Comment: What is the original line supposed to accomplish?

Comment: `$('#popNewClient form').validate({onfocusout: function(element) {$(element).valid();}});`